# How to alter variable for ECK entity?

Tags: 8, hooks, entities

We are using the [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) module where we have created component eck_highlight (machine name). How would we be able to modify the variable array using a preprocess hook?

Eck_highlight component has this field:

- Field Reference to content types: basic, article, and event

Goal:

Call the preprocess to store 'info' array to vars (i.e. vars['info']). The info variable will be passed into the [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) template so we can use to output information.

```
mymodule_preprocess_eck_highlight(&$vars) {
    $vars['info'] += [
       'id' => 'some-id',
       'height' => 'some-height',
       'width' => 'some-width',
       'src' => 'src1'
    ];
}
```

We have tried to do the following but cannot alter the variables.

1. mymodule_preprocess_eck_highlight(&$vars)
2. mytheme_preprocess_eck_highlight(&$vars)

Comment: Is this the correct hook to use?

Comment: I ended up finding the correct hook. I will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am adding an answer so anyone who comes across this that i was able to resolve the issue. I had to use mymodule_preprocess_eck_entity(&$vars).

When i tried to use the machine name in place of eck_entity, it did not work.